# My python code to check for element exists in a list is not working

Tags: python

I have a SQL query result of 695 `records` which I need to strip out the matches to my 52 items in `_ids` list.

```
_ids = [44226, 44303, ...]

records = [
    (44226, datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 27, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 
    8, 27, 21, 0), '0.50'), 
    (44227, datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 30, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 
    8, 30, 22, 30), '0'), ...
]
```

Using the [Is there a short contains function for lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists) and looping over my `records` is always resulting in `True`.

```
for i in records:
    if i[0] not in _ids:
        # pop from list
```

Any recommendations to efficiently return list only list of records that match `_ids` list?

Comment: Is there a good reason not to just do this in the SQL query directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what it looks from your comment, you are calling `.pop()` inside the loop. This will modify the list while iterating it at the same time, leading to unexpected results. Try this:

```
import datetime 

_ids = [44226, 44303]

records = [
    (44226, datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 27, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 
    8, 27, 21, 0), '0.50'), 
    (44227, datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 30, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 
    8, 30, 22, 30), '0'),
]

print([row[0] for row in records if row[0] in _ids])
```

This uses a conditional list comprehension to return only the `id`s that match.

Update: An edit request to this answer pointed out that it is a good idea to define `_ids` as a `set` so that you can have constant time complexity in your lookup, i.e.:

```
_ids = {44226, 44303}
```