# Getting UnboundLocalError in Python 3.8 program

Tags: python-3.8

It keeps coming up with UnboundLocalError: local variable 'can_i_get' referenced before assignment right here.

```
            #this makes you have to have a certain level to get better weapon.  

    #ignore this --> 
             if player_level == (10,12):  #checks if there a high level
             can_i_get = True  #this checks if its True
            elif player_level == (1,9):  #checks if there not a high level
             can_i_get = False  #this checks if its False
            else:print("you cant use that ")  

             #this makes you able to get better weapons  



     # create a dictionary of the possible moves and randomly select the damage it does when selected

            if can_i_get: 
             What = {"ROOF": random.randint(18, 10000),
                     "Power Sword": random.randint(10, 21000), #this makes the damage random
                     "Mega heal": random.randint(20, 10000)} #why do i need to keep adding these?
```

Comment: imapancake, what is the value of `player_level` when you get your error?

Comment: I have a level system that I created if you like I could post it

Comment: What I am getting it is that if `player_level` does not trigger either of the two conditional blocks, then `can_i_get` will be undefined. So, you need to (temporarily) echo out `player_level` before using `can_i_get` to see what is going on. Would you do that now?

Comment: ok I will try it

Comment: Ps: player_level value is 1

Comment: OK, so you are expecting the `elif player_level == (1,9)` clause to be run. I don't do Python - is it legitimate syntax to do `==` on an array set? I think you need to do "array contains" here.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are doing it wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists

Comment: interesting it's not telling me that == is not valid syntax

Comment: Let me know how you get on with the other syntax.