# Searching for a string value in a list

Tags: python, string, list, search

My list is a=['Name','Age','Subject'] and I want to search whether an input by the user exists in this list or not.

Let's say the user enters x='name', how do I search for x in this list a (case-insensitively)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a short contains function for lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists)

Comment: `x in list` It is case sensitive. `x.casefold() in list` it is case insensitive.

Comment: @Shadowcodder no, only if the items in `list` are also casefolded.  The example has mixed case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code might help you. You have to `string` modification methods `lower()/upper()`. I used lower here, it changes any case of each character to lower case. e.g. after using `'NaMe'.lower()` to `NaMe`changed to `'name''. I changed both the input string and list elements and checked whether the input is in the list. That's all.

**Code**

```
a=['Name','Age','Subject'] 
a = [a.lower() for a in a]
user_input = input("Put the input: ").lower()
if user_input in a:
    print("Match")
    
else:
    print("Mismatch")
```

**Output**

```
> Put the input: AGE
> Match
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a case sensitive search in the list you can do,

```
x = "name" # input from the user
l = ['Name','Age','Subject']

if x in l:
    print("Found a match")
else:
    print("No match")
```

If you want to do a case insensitive search in the list you can do,

```
x = "name" # input from the user
l = ['Name','Age','Subject']

if x.lower() in list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), l)):
    print("Found a match")
else:
    print("No match")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```py
a = ['Name','Age','Subject']
x = input('').title()
b = x in a
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows Without casting the whole list:

```
b = input("please enter a string:")
ismatch =b.title() in a
print(ismatch)

>>> please enter a string:
>Age
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a=['Name','Age','Subject']
if 'Name' in a:
    print "yes"
```