# string contain either one of two numbers

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement

I'd like to perform an if condition if a specific list item contains either one out of several numbers:

```
if firststring[1] == 100 or 40 or 80 or 67:
    print('hallo')
```

Does this code make sense?

Comment: `if firststring[1] in [100, 40, 80, 67]: ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a short contains function for lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists)

Comment: What is the value of `firststring[1]`? number as int? number as string? string that contains a number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work!, the value can be both int or str..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `in`:

```py
if firststring[1] in (100, 40, 80, 67):
    print('hi =)')
```