# python get dictionary key from value is list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
first_dict = {'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
              'b': ['4', '5'],
              'c': ['6'],
              }
```

```
second_dict = {'1': 'wqeewe',
               '2': 'efsafa',
               '4': 'fsasaf',
               '6': 'kgoeew',
               '7': 'fkowew'
               }
```

I want to have a third dict that will contain the key of second_dict and its corresponding value from first_dict's key. This way, I will have :

```
third_dict = {'1' : 'a',
              '2' : 'a',
              '4' : 'b',
              '6' : 'c',
              '7' : None,

}
```

here is my way:

```
def key_return(name):
  for key, value in first_dict.items():
    if name == value:
      return key
    if isinstance(value, list) and name in value:
      return key
  return None
```

reference:
[Python return key from value, but its a list in the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134423/python-return-key-from-value-but-its-a-list-in-the-dictionary)

However, I wondering that the another way using dict.get() or something else.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are all values in the first collection lists? Then your first test is not useful.

Comment: As per current use case it is better to `set` instead of `list` because you are using membership test, which is faster on `set` as compared to `list`.

Comment: @Mudassir I see. It didn't work if there is ['1', '4']. So I need to try another way

Comment: You can also test `name == value or name in value`. The second test will only happen if the first one is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version with `a_dict.get()`

```
third_dict = {i: {i:k for k,v in first_dict.items() for i in v}.get(i) for i in second_dict.keys()}
```

this part `{i:k for k,v in first_dict.items() for i in v}`

creates a dict like `{'1': 'a', '2': 'a', '3': 'a', '4': 'b', '5': 'b', '6': 'c'}`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like that:

#### Code

```py
first_dict = {'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
              'b': ['4', '5'],
              'c': ['6'],
              }

second_dict = {'1': 'wqeewe',
               '2': 'efsafa',
               '4': 'fsasaf',
               '6': 'kgoeew',
               '7': 'fkowew'
               }

third_dict = dict()

for second_key in second_dict.keys():
    found = False
    for first_key, value in first_dict.items():
        if second_key in value:
            third_dict.setdefault(second_key, first_key )
            found = True
    if not found:
        third_dict.setdefault(second_key, None)
                    
print(third_dict)
```

##### Output:

```
{'1': 'a', '2': 'a', '4': 'b', '6': 'c', '7': None}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can map the values in the first dictionary to their keys with:

```
values_map = dict([a for k, v in first_dict.items() for a in zip(v, k*len(v))])
```

then use this map to create the third dictionary:

```
third_dict = {key: values_map.get(key) for key, value in second_dict.items()}
```

Since I get that the first_dict may contain single values instead of list you may want first to convert those values to list with:

```
first_dict = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]) if isinstance(x[1], list) else (x[0], [str(x[1])]), first_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = {
    x: k
    for k, xs in first_dict.items()
    for x in xs
    if x in second_dict
}
```

this creates `1:a , 2:a, 4:b` etc. If you also want missing keys like `7:None` join it with a dummy dict:

```
res = {k: None for k in second_dict} | {
    x: k
    for k, xs in first_dict.items()
    for x in xs
    if x in second_dict
}
```