# Understanding hangman blank letter generator

Tags: python

I have this line of code in a hangman program

```
word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in word]
```

and it takes the word that was picked and puts '-' in place of the letters that weren't guessed yet.

I just don't understand how the line works. How is there an if statement and a for loop inside a list? What is this if statement doing `if letter in used_letters`?

If someone could break it down for me I feel like it would make way more sense.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-does-in-operator-work-on-list-in-Python

Comment: This is a [list comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a short contains function for lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists)

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the line into something else (such as many lines) to understand how it works?

Answer (score -1):

`True if True else False` => True

`True if False else False` => False

If you take it apart, your cycle looks something like this:

```
word_list = []
for letter in word:
    if letter in used_letters:
        word_list.append(letter)
    else:
        word_list.append('-')
```

Comment: That's not really a description that helps the OP

Comment: @OneCricketeer ...

Comment: What if they don't know what a ternary expression is? How do booleans help explain what will end up in `word_list`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer A clear application of this expression.