# can you do a if value == any part of a List in python

Tags: python

```
if Command == wikiL:
    wikipediaSearch()
```

That is my code and the list is

```
wikiL = ['Wiki', 'wiki', 'WIKI', 'wIKI', 'Wikipedia', 'wikipedia', 'WIKIPEDIA', 'wIKIPEDIA']
```

Is there anyway I can do this because when I try it doesn't do anything

Comment: Use `in`: `if command in wikiL:`

Comment: if you use `command.lower()` then you can create shorter list - only with lower case examples - `['wiki', 'wikipedia']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if item is in an array / list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251709/check-if-item-is-in-an-array-list)

Answer (score 1):

In Python there is the `in` operator you just have to do:

```
if Command in wikil:
     wikipediaSearch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that:

```
if value in list:
    <then do what you want to do here>
```