# Array in python in nested for-loops

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to create an operator where the user types in the position on the chessboard and my program will print out if it's standing on a black or a white square. The problem is that my if statement will not run through my arrays properly.

```
pos = input (f'Hvilken posisjon står brikken på? ') 

bokstav = pos[0]                

tall = int(pos[1])              

for x in bokstav:
  for y in str(tall):
    
    partall_svart = ['b','d','f','h']
    partall_hvit = ['a','c','e','g']

    print (partall_svart)
    print (partall_hvit)
    
    if x == partall_svart and int(y) % 2 == 0:
        print (f'Posisjon: {bokstav}{tall}\nSvart')
    
    elif x == partall_svart and int(y) % 2 == 1:
        print (f'Posisjon: {bokstav}{tall}\nHvit')
    
    if x == partall_hvit and int(y) % 2 == 0:
        print (f'Posisjon: {bokstav}{tall}\nHvit')
    
    elif x == partall_hvit and int(y) % 2 == 1:
        print (f'Posisjon: {bokstav}{tall}\nSvart')
```

Comment: Which `if` statement do you mean? Are you trying to check whether `x` is one of the items in `partall_svart`? Use `in`, not `==`.

Comment: This question is answered here: [Check if item is in an array / list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251709/check-if-item-is-in-an-array-list)

Comment: The code-point of `aA` is an odd number. So, since the square `A1` is black, all you need to do is check whether the parity of the row-number is the same as the parity of column-letter code-point: i.e. `svart = ord(pos[0]) % 2 == int(pos[1]) % 2`. The for-loops aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could just make a number from the letter part too, and then use `%2` on both parts. As ekhumoro's suggestion with `ord()` may be a bit esoteric, this code uses `find()` instead:

```
pos = input (f'Hvilken posisjon star brikken pa? ')

bokstav = pos[0]                
bokstavtall = "abcdefgh".find(bokstav.lower()) + 1

tall = int(pos[1])              

print (f'Posisjon: {bokstav}{tall}\n{"Svart" if tall % 2 == bokstavtall % 2 else "Hvit"}')
```

Comment: Has the world really become so dumbed-down now that learning what a simple function like [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) does is considered too onerous? I could also have suggested `int(pos[0], 18) - 9` - but presumably that would be considered even more "esoteric" as it implies an elementary understanding of number bases.

Comment: @ekhumoro I like the 18-base more, to be honest. Remembering ASCII codes is just less intuitive.

Comment: Surely the whole point of `ord` is to save you the trouble of remembering the code-points? But in any case, it's the parity that matters, not the exact numbers.

Comment: Remembering 1 bit of an ASCII code is for sure something what people do all the time :-)

Comment: I'm referring to the [mathematical parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)), which simply means the oddness/evenness of an integer. I think most people know that `65` and `97` are odd numbers, and can make the reasonable assumption that the relevant code-points are sequential ;-)