# Item of a list is not defined in an 'if' statement

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

This code should warn me if an element in the second list is already in the first, after having put the first in lower case.

```
current_users = ['id_1','id_2','id_3', 'ID_4', 'id_5']
current_users_case = [current_user_case.lower() for current_user_case in current_users]

new_users = ['id_5','id_4','id_7', 'id_8', 'id_9']

for new_user in new_users:
  if new_user == current_user_case:
    print("Sorry, ID already taken")
  else:
    print("ID available")
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from c5n9ss import *
  File "/home/runner/C5py/c5n9ss.py", line 11, in <module>
    if new_user == current_user_case:
NameError: name 'current_user_case' is not defined
```

But if I test the first two lines in the Python shell, I get the lowered list correctly.

I don't understand the error I get.

Comment: did the answer help you? If it did, would you mind accepting it and putting closure to you question? You can do so by clicking on the check mark by the answer, or you can wait for more answers to arrive.

Comment: Thanks, I need more time to test it though.

Comment: absolutely. Take your time to test it and ensure that it works before making a choice of accepting or not accepting an answer.

Comment: Were you able to test this suggestions in the answer?

Comment: thanks, going to check it this Thursday, as I've been not at work, I'm sorry for the delay

Comment: Do you have any further questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is good. Just make 2 changes:

1. Change `current_user_case:` to `current_users_case:` (Notice it is users not user in the variable name)
2. Change `if new_user == current_user_case:` to `if new_user in current_users_case:`

```
current_users = ['id_1','id_2','id_3', 'ID_4', 'id_5']
current_users_case = [current_user_case.lower() for current_user_case in current_users]

new_users = ['id_5','id_4','id_7', 'id_8', 'id_9']

for new_user in new_users:
  if new_user in current_users_case:
    print("Sorry, ID already taken")
  else:
    print("ID available")
```

When `new_user` is id_5, you want to compare it to all items in current_users_case. If you compare it to the list, then you won't get a match because string (id_5) is not a list. When you use `in`, you are checking whether id_5 is in the list and then your code works as expected.

Comment: @2: see: [Check if item is in an array / list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251709/check-if-item-is-in-an-array-list)

Comment: Your suggestions work flawlessly. To be honest, I understand the second comment you wrote, but I don't understand the first one. The lines you're referring to seem to be the same both in your code and mine.

Comment: @RobertCode look at your code closely at this line `if new_user == current_user_case:`. The variable on the right side you wrote is current_user_case. It should be current_users_case. Your variable has a missing `s` after user. That's what point `1` is highlighting in my answer.

Comment: Thanks I understand better what I did wrong.