# HTMLParser or urllib2 unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to use HTMLParser and urllib2 to get to an image file

```
content = urllib2.urlopen( imgurl.encode('utf-8') ).read()
try:
    p = MyHTMLParser(  )
    p.feed( content )
    p.download_file( )
    p.close()
except Exception,e:
    print e
```

MyHTMLParser:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)        
        self.url=""
        self.outfile = "some.png"

    def download_file(self):
        urllib.urlretrieve( self.url, self.outfile )

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "a":
           # after some manipulation here, self.url will have a img url
           self.url = "http://somewhere.com/Fondue%C3%A0.png"
```

when i run the script, i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 59, in <module>
p.feed( data )
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 114, in feed
self.goahead(0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 158, in goahead
k = self.parse_starttag(i)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 305, in parse_starttag
attrvalue = self.unescape(attrvalue)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 472, in unescape
return re.sub(r"&(#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w{1,8}));", replaceEntities, s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 56: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Using the suggestions i found in the found, i did the .encode('utf-8') method, but it still gives me error. how to fix this ? thanks

Comment: That error message should come with a file name and line number pointing you to which line is giving the error.  Which line is it?

Comment: @SamMussmann, i added the actual trace back. thanks

Comment: HTML parsers parse HTML. That's an actual image. Why don't you just download the file?

Comment: @Blender, actually the img url comes after i do some string manipulation during runtime. So i won't know the exact url at the start.

Comment: @dorothy: But the problem remains: is `url` pointing to an HTML page (like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Greatest_common_divisor_chart.png)), or is it the URL for a PNG image (like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Greatest_common_divisor_chart.png))?

Comment: @Blender, yes, the self.url will eventually contain the PNG image link. The html page i will have to parse it to get to that png image link and then store in self.url

Comment: here's an [example how `Content-type` header is used to get character encoding and HTMLParser is used to get cities names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13517891/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
content = urllib2.urlopen( url.encode('utf-8') ).read()
```

with

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

To decode the response into unicode.

Comment: @dorothy: utf-8 is *not* the only character encoding that may be used in an html document. It may be specified in http header (e.g., `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`), inside the html (e.g., `<meta charset="utf-8">`), [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)