# Python check if an item is in a list

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm very much a beginner to python. What I want to do is see which list an item is in. What I have is some lists set up like:

```
    l1 = [1,2,3]  
    l2 = [4,5,6]  
    l3 = [7,8,9]
```

And let's say I want to find which list the item 5 is in.
What I'm currently doing is:

```
    if l1.index(5)!=False:
        print 1
    elif l2.index(5)!=False:
        print 2
    elif l3.index(5)!=False:
        print 3
```

But this doesn't work. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Find in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `in` operator to check for membership:

```
>>> 5 in [1, 3, 4]
False
>>> 5 in [1, 3, 5]
True
```

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't know about that operator before

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer with the "in" operator, you should do that with a loop by inserting all the list to one list and then send it to a function and loop over it. Note that the first 'in' belongs to the for loop and the second 'in' is the operator:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]  
l2 = [4,5,6]  
l3 = [7,8,9]

all_lst = [l1,l2,l3]

list_contain_num(all_lst) 

def list_contain_num(all_lst):
    for lst in all_lst:
        if 5 in lst:
            print('the containing list is: ' + str(lst) )
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if l1.index(5)!=False:
>     print 1
> ```

The `index()` method does not return True or False, it returns the index.  So you would change this to:

```
if l1.index(5) >= 0:
    print 1
```

Comment: What if it's not in the list?

Comment: That's what the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) are for : ).  Actually, it will raise a ValueError.  Switching back from Java I was thinking it would return -1.  At least the part about not comparing the returned value to a boolean literal is correct and helpful.