# How do I search a list for a number between two values?

Tags: python, list, search

In Python I have a list of numbers that have been added using `.append()`. I need to search my list to find if it contains any particular integer between two set values eg/ between 30 and 40.

I know I can use the code `if x in n:` to search a list for a single integer but I do not know how to do this for multiple integers.

Comment: Do you have any more code that you can show for this?

Comment: create a new list `[x for x in number_list if 30 < x < 40]`

Comment: Got it sorted thanks all

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function for you. It returns a list with all the values between the low and high limits given, including duplicates. If you want to get rid of duplicates, use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set). I wouldn't sort it first because that would be less efficient than just iterating through the list.

```
def between(l1,low,high):
    l2 = []
    for i in l1:
        if(i > low and i < high):
            l2.append(i)
    return l2


l = [1,3,4,5,1,4,2,7,6,5] 

print( between(l,2,5) )
```

> [3, 4, 4]

**edit:**

Or, hey, let's use list comprehension if you're into the whole brevity thing!

```
l = [1,3,4,5,1,4,2,7,6,5]
l2 = [i for i in l if i > 2 and i < 5]    
print(l2)
```

> [3, 4, 4]

Comment: `2 < i < 5` even briefer :)

Answer (score 2):

Some of above answers are efficient. I am just giving an approach with sorting the list.

```
filter(lambda x: x>30 and x<40,sorted(a))
```

a is input list

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code yet, I'll give you a simple algorithm:

```
for every number in the list
    if the number is greater than 30 and less than 40
        do something with the number
```

For example, if you simply need to know if such a number exists, you can set a boolean value to true once the condition has been met.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9542768/4561047) includes a more abbreviated way to accomplish what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
min=30
max=40

nums = [8, 32, 35, 180]
nums.append(13)

for x in nums:
   if x > min and x < max: print x
```

Comment: `x > min and x < max` can be written more legible as `min < x < max` - does no one use chained comparisons?