# How to read a certain line in text file using Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a text file with a location and its coordinates on a new line e.g.

```
A&AB
42.289567
-83.717143
AH
42.276620
-83.739620)
```

I have a for loop that iterates through this list and if the location matches the user input, it returns the next two lines (latitude and longitude). How do I do this in a neat fashion using Python? I know how to do this in C++ but I have no idea with Python.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's yet another approach to the same soup:

```
def match(name):
    with open("locat.txt") as f:
        #gr = [iter(f)]*3
        #for tag lat, lon in zip(*gr):
        for tag, lat, lon in zip(f, f, f):
            if tag.rstrip() == name:
                return float(lat.rstrip('\n)')), float(lon.rstrip('\n)'))
    return None

print(match('AY'))
print(match('xy'))
```

produces

```
(42.27, -83.73)
None
```

It only tries to match the given name to every third line and it returns `None` if no match is found.

Note: there is no error checking, so you need to be sure the input data is correct (e.g. if any of the entries lack a row, i.e. a coordinate value, it would not work. In such case one of the other answers above which check the match against each row would work better and re-synch automatically).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know, in fact it was working fine. I did it to enable it to remove the parens in one go, otherwise `rstrip` would find the \n only

Comment: You can forget the zip iter though, you already have an iterator you can simply `zip(f,f,f)`

Answer (score 1):

Python iterators can be advanced manually, as well as implicitly. Assuming you'll only be reading a single value, not checking over and over (and don't want to store all values in memory for whatever reason), you could do:

```
def find_latlong(locname, locfile):
    with open(locfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.rstrip() == locname:
                try:
                    return float(next(f)), float(next(f))
                except StopIteration:
                    break
    raise ValueError("location {!r} not found".format(locname))
```

This just looks for the line matching the provided name in the provided file, and manually iterates to get the next two lines when it is found.

An alternative that assumes the exact three line pattern, and doesn't check the non-name lines:

```
from future_builtins import map, zip  # Only on Python 2

def find_latlong(locname, locfile):
    with open(locfile) as f:
        f = map(str.rstrip, f)
        for header, lat, lng in zip(f, f, f):  # Reads three lines at a time
            if header == locname:
                return float(lat), float(lng)
    raise ValueError("location {!r} not found".format(locname))
```

Comment: it works, but it checks the string against the coords, unnecessarily

Comment: True. Could explicitly advance the iterator, or use ugly hacks. Lot of options here.

Comment: @Pynchia: Added an example that avoids checking lines aside from name lines.

Comment: Except you will get an error casting  to float with the paren

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you! I'd missed that! I've corrected mine as well

Comment: @ShadowRanger you can't/shouldn't use `long`

Comment: and the code still does not cope well with the extra `)`. check the input sample

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Ah, missed that. Not entirely sure if that paren was legitimately part of the input (it seems a little odd). I figure the OP can fix that if needed.

Comment: @Pynchia: Ugh, yeah, I suppose. I run in Python 3 most of the time, so it's not a name I make an effort to avoid so much (also, I don't think I've ever intentionally used the `long` constructor, even in Py2; I use `int`, and Python promotes to `long` if needed).

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import dropwhile
def get_data(fle, lne):
    with open(fle) as f:
        dw = dropwhile(lambda x: x.rstrip() != lne,f)
        _, a, b = next(dw,""), next(dw, "").rstrip(")\n"), next(dw,"").rstrip(")")
        return  (a,b) if b else (None, None)

lat, lon = get_data("foo.txt","A&AB")
if lat:
   # you have a match
```

Comment: I think your `dropwhile` condition is backwards.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, how do you mean backwards?

Comment: You're dropping while the line is the one you're looking for, not until you find the line you're looking for.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes, `!=` instead of `==`

Answer (score -1):

Check out this answer for some great options
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list).
The simplest answer is that you can use the `in` operator, or `matches = [x for x in lst if fulfills_some_condition(x)]`. But click on the above link for a more detailed answer. Assuming, of course, that you are iterating through a list as described.

Answer (score -1):

As a language, Python emphasizes readability. In addition to advanced solutions using iterators provided by others, here is one using the simple `readline` method on the file object:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    while True:
        desc =f.readline()
        lat = f.readline()
        lng = f.readline()
        if not desc:
            return None, None
        if desc.strip() == wanted:
            return float(lat), float(lng)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think what you can do is build a list of tuples, where each tuple will be of the type (Location,Latitude,Longitude)

You can do that as follows :

```
with open("filename","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# This is essentially splitting the lines into 
# locations, latitudes and longitudes and then merges them using zip
# to get a list of tuples
locations = zip(lines[0::3],lines[1::3], lines[2::3])

# Assuming that the userLocation contains user input
userLocation = 'foobar'

# Find the user input in our list
result = [x for x in locations if locations[0] == userLocation]

# Print the matches
for r in results:
    print "Latitude = " + str(r[1]) + "   Longitude = " + str(r[2])
```

Comment: This is a very poor way to tackle the problem so I can see exactly why it was downvoted, you keep multiple copies in memory when there is no need to at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - If I free off the memory for locations list, then how would it consume extra memory?

Comment: Where are you freeing of memory? Every answer has managed to solve the problem by only keeping at most a few lines in memory, yours has the whole file and then some