# How to compare inside list values in python

Tags: python, list

I have to find 6 distincts words in a bunch of lists. For example in first list, there will be word 'me', in second word 'us'.

I've already found the line number using this code:

```
def creatList(file):
try:
    for i,line in enumerate(file,1):
```

and pass found values to another function,

```
line=(line.rstrip()).split()
rawList=[]

rawList.append(line)

creatRuleFile(i,rawList)
```

inside that function,

```
def creatRuleFile(p,new):
   print(new)
   print("{0}. {1}".format(p, new))
   lookup ='me'
   if p==1:
      print('found at line:', lookup)
```

my code is not working as I want... appreciate if you can suggest an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Show us the detailed error info.. Replace `(line.rstrip()).split()` with `line.rstrip().split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Has been answered before:
[Python: Find in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

use something like

```
stuff_I_want_to_find = "whatever"
if stuff_I_want_to_find in myList:
    index = myList.find(stuff_I_want_to_find)
```

now you have to iterate over your lists and over your words, which will essentially be two loops.