# Print specific value index from key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has many values per key.
How do I print a specific value from that key?

for example, my key is "CHMI" but it has 14 values associated with it.  How do I print only `CHMI: 48680` value?

```
CHMI: ['CHMI', '16', '16.09', '15.92', '16.01', '0.02', '0.13', '48680', '17.26', '12.6', '1.96', '12.24', '14.04', '23.15']
```

Comment: Check out [Python Find in List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a dictionary with a key:value pair where the value is a list.

To reference values within this list, you do your normal dictionary reference, ie

```
 dict['chmi']
```

But you need to add a way to manipulate your list.  You can use any of the list methods, or just use a list slice, ie

```
dict['chmi'][0]
```

will return the first element of the list referenced by key chmi.  You can use

```
dict['chmi'][dict['chmi'].index('48680')]
```

to reference the 48680 element.  What I am doing here is calling the

```
list.index(ele)
```

method, which returns the index of your element, then I am referencing the element by using a slice.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work!  I had tried that syntax before but didn't work but i think i was missing parenthesis or something.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand why you would want to do it (if you already know what value you want, why not use it directly?), it can be done with the `index` method of lists, which returns the index of the provided value in the list

```
d = {'CHMI': ['CHMI', '16', '16.09', '15.92', '16.01', '0.02', '0.13', '48680', '17.26', '12.6', '1.96', '12.24', '14.04', '23.15']}

chmi_values = d['CHMI']

print(chmi_values[chmi_values.index('48680')])
>> '48680'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the 8th element of the list, or an element with a specific value? If you already know the value - then you can print it without looking it up in the list so I assume you want to just retrieve one of the elements:

```
print(my_dict['CHMI'][7])
```

This is equivalent to:

```
values = my_dict['CHMI']
eight_value = my_dict[7]
print(eigth_value)
```

If this is not what you need, I'm afraid you'll have to clarify your question a little :)

Comment: I would like the eigth value of my list.  I actually have over 2,000 keys in my dictionary and each one has a different value at the 8th element, so i am trying to determine how to access that index value specifically so eventually i can run loop for each key and "do something" to that 8th element

Comment: Ok then you should have a solution above ☺️