# Returning an element from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to return an individual from the list that has fitness greater than or equal to 90. To do so I have to sort the list, but I think there is a better way.. how can I do this withought sorting. Like at the instant when the if condition becomes true print that perticular individual from the list.

```
    if any(individual.fitness >= 90 for individual in individuals):
        print('Threshold met!')
        individuals = sorted(
            individuals, key=lambda individual: individual.fitness, reverse=True)
        return individuals[0]
```

Comment: Just *any* individual in the list with fitness greater than 90?

Comment: iterate through the list and print out when the fitness is 90

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Find in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Comment: @JeremyFisher the code already does. It just doesn't fish out the element it finds.

Comment: it looks to me like you could just use `m = max(individuals, key=lambda x: x.fitness)` then only return `if m.fitness >= 90`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that always succeeds, though. Edit: and requires an unnecessary full traversal

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes any individual that has fitness greater than 90

Comment: @EshanPandey not if there are no individuals with fitness greater than 90...?

Comment: You really ought to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list because it covers your case exactly - it tells you how to retrieve the first value found by the generator expression you already have.

Comment: What about some reaction to given answers?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are :) :

```
for individual in individuals:
    if individual.fitness >= 90:
        print('Threshold met!')
        return individual
return None
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list = [11, 35, 90, 95, 98, 89, 85]
list2 = [i for i in list if i>= 90]
print(list2)
```

Output of the above code is: `[90, 95, 98]`

It will return the list of values of your criteria. If you want to get every element individually, add these kines:

```
for individual in list2:
    print (individual)
```

These lines will give this output:

`90
 95
 98`