# Search a Python list for a specific string using unknown elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that holds multiple, duplicate strings that come from a .csv file:

```
listOne = ['strOne', 'strTwo', 'strThree', 'strOne', 'strTwo', 'strOne']
```

and want to create a new list from it to hold only unique strings:

```
listTwo = ['strOne', 'strTwo', 'strThree']
```

I read the file and populate the original list like this:

```
def createOrigList(filename):
    dataFile = open(filename,'r')
    for line in dataFile:
        origList.append(line)

def createListOne():
    for item in origList:
        tempList = item.split(',')
        strOne = tempList[0].strip()
        listOne.append(strOne)
```

I've tried to implement [this earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list) and use the Python `if (... not in ...)` conditional nested into a `for` loop to populate `listTwo` but when I try to print out `listTwo`, nothing has been added.

```
def createListTwo():
    for item in listOne: 
    item = item.strip()
    if (item not in listTwo):
        listTwo.append(item)
```

Am I not comparing exact strings when trying to create `listTwo`?

Comment: You can use a python set: `listTwo = list(set(listOne))`

Comment: have you defined list one and list two outside of the functions createListOne and CreateList two?if not,list add them before any function listOne=[],listTwo=[]

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan yes, the lists are defined outside the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast it to a `set`. Like this:

```
listTwo = set(listOne)
print(listTwo)
```

This will only keep the unique elements in `listOne`.

Answer (score 2):

As it has already been answered you can use python set.

However, nobody asked about whether you need to keep the order of the original list since set does not keep the order of the original list. If you need to keep the order of the original list you can use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

listOne = ['strOne', 'strTwo', 'strThree', 'strOne', 'strTwo', 'strOne']
listTwo = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(listOne))
print(listTwo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
listTwo = [item.strip() for item in set(listOne)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is use  SET , it will remove all duplicate strings. Further more you can convert it into list

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` to remove duplicates in the list.

```
listOne = list(set(listOne))
```

If the values in list has spaces, then you can strip each item in the list and make it a `set`

```
listOne = list(set([x.strip() for x in listOne]))
```

Remember, both the above answers will not retain the order of elements.