# How to search a list for two items in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need some help with searching a single list for two different pieces of data, how could this be done so that if this if both pieces of data it will output the values are found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Find in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a couple of `in` operators:

```
def both_in_list(lst, a, b):
    return a in lst and b in lst
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]

if (6 in list1) and (6 in list2):

    print("The elements that you're looking for is there!")

else:

    print("One of the lists does not that the element you're looking for!")
```

Comment: Use the boolean `and`, not the bitwise `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Used a couple `in` operators to do this.

```
    list = [2,4,8,14,16]
    if 2 in list and 4 in list
        print("2 and 4 are found in this list.")
    else:
        print("These numbers are not found in this list.")
```