# Python equivalent of c++ find_if

Tags: python, syntax

Is there a built-in python equivalent of `std::find_if` to find the first element of a list for which a given condition is `true`? In other words, something like the `index()` function of a list, but with an arbitrary unary predicate rather than just a test for equality.

I don't want to use list comprehension, because the specific predicate I have in mind is somewhat expensive to compute.

Comment: Are you looking for the 'in' command?: if x in list: do something.

Comment: Did you read this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9542768/10077 Look at "Finding the first occurrence".

Comment: Seems like you want [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)... *"it allows us to conveniently capture a "witness" for an `any()` expression"*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a tip from [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9542738/10077), and borrowing from the answer taras posted, I came up with this:

```
>>> lst=[1,2,10,3,5,3,4]
>>> next(n for n in lst if n%5==0)
10
```

A slight modification will give you the index rather than the value:

```
>>> next(idx for idx,n in enumerate(lst) if n%5==0)
2
```

Now, if there was no match this will raise an exception StopIteration. You might want use a function that handles the exception and returns `None` if there was no match:

```
def first_match(iterable, predicate):
    try:
        return next(idx for idx,n in enumerate(iterable) if predicate(n))
    except StopIteration:
        return None

lst=[1,2,10,3,5,3,4]
print(first_match(lst, lambda x: x%5 == 0))
```

Note that this uses a generator expression, not a list comprehension. A list comprehension would apply the condition to every member of the list and produce a list of all matches. This applies it to each member until it finds a match and then stops, which is the minimum work to solve the problem.

Comment: Hey! I found the problem of using next() in a lambda interesting, so I looked around a bit for a solution akin to the dict. get()'s default value argument, which substitutes the exception with a default return. I don't know whether this was already the case when you posted, but next() actually works the same. So you could even drop the separate error handling function and reduce your solution to next((n for n in lst if n%5==0), None)

Answer (score 1):

Say, you have some predicate function `pred` and a list `lst`.
You can use `itertools.dropwhile` to get the first element in `lst`,
for which `pred` returns `True` with

```
itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: not pred(x), lst).next()
```

It skips all elements for which `pred(x)` is `False` and `.next()`
yields you the value for which pred(x) is `True`.

**Edit:**

A sample use to find the first element in `lst` divisible by `5`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [1,2,10,3,5,3,4]
>>> pred = lambda x: x % 5 == 0 
>>> itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: not pred(x), lst).next()
10
```

Comment: Using the answer I linked in comments above, I was also able to accomplish this with just `next(n for n in lst if n%5==0)`.

Comment: Yes, definitely, but OP wishes not to use a list comprehension.

Comment: There's no list comprehension there. Only a generator expression.

Comment: Well, I am completely fine with your approach, yet they do share the same syntax construct.

Comment: Thank you for this good answer; I accepted the other one because it is "pure" python and doesn't require any imports.

Comment: @MikeHawk, I find the accepted answer more plausible myself. In fact my approach does the same "under the hood" (if one updated it to return the index instead of the value)