# How to separate JSON output for Chatterbot

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, chatterbot

I'm creating a simple chatbot with Python and the chatterbot library. I've been able to get something able to work, where the user inputs something and the bot responds based on a `.json` of patterns and responses.
Every time I execute the bot is able to tell what "tag" the user input and responds accordingly only in this format: `"patterns": ["cya", "See you later", "Goodbye", "I am Leaving", "Have a Good day"],` But I would like it to remove the quotations, commas, etc and just pick one response at random. I've tried this tokenizing thing? Seems not to be working
**Code**

```
## MODULES
from chatterbot import ChatBot #This imports the chatbot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer #Method used for training the chatbot
import chatterbot #Just in case
import os

## BOT VARIABLES
bot = ChatBot("Test") #This creates the chatbot and names it 'Test'
trainer = ListTrainer(bot) #Creates the trainer
data = "C:/Users/PAVILION/Desktop/ChatBotTest2/INTS/"

for files in os.listdir(data):
    conv = open(data + files, 'r').readlines() #This opens the direrctory full of data
    trainer.train(conv) #This trains the chatbot trainer with data from the directory

## CHATTERBOT OUTPUT
while True:
    message = input("You: ")

    if message.strip() != "Bye":
        response = bot.get_response(message)
        print("ChatBot: ", response)

    if message.strip() == "Bye":
        print("ChatBot: Farewell")
        break
```

**Intentions.json**

```
{"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day", "Whats up"],
     "responses": ["Hello!", "Good to see you again!", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "goodbye",
     "patterns": ["cya", "See you later", "Goodbye", "I am Leaving", "Have a Good day"],
     "responses": ["Sad to see you go :(", "Talk to you later", "Goodbye!"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "age",
     "patterns": ["how old", "how old is tim", "what is your age", "how old are you", "age?"],
     "responses": ["I am 18 years old!", "18 years young!"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "name",
     "patterns": ["what is your name", "what should I call you", "whats your name?"],
     "responses": ["You can call me Tim.", "I'm Tim!", "I'm Tim aka Tech With Tim."],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "shop",
     "patterns": ["Id like to buy something", "whats on the menu", "what do you reccommend?", "could i get something to eat"],
     "responses": ["We sell chocolate chip cookies for $2!", "Cookies are on the menu!"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "hours",
     "patterns": ["when are you guys open", "what are your hours", "hours of operation"],
     "responses": ["We are open 7am-4pm Monday-Friday!"],
     "context_set": ""
    }
]
}
```

json was gotten from Tech with Tim tutorial btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load that `json` into a python object by removing the top level 'intents' (it's not needed) and loading the list into a variable;

```
intents = [

    {"tag": "greeting",
    "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day", "Whats up"],
    "responses": ["Hello!", "Good to see you again!", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
    "context_set": ""
    },

    # rest of json pasted here
]
```

You can then access the `dict`s in the list by using `next` and a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

```
selected_intent = next((i for i in intents if i['tag'] == 'greeting'), None)
```

Now `selected_intent` will be the intent `dict` from the list if the `tag` is `greeting` (in this example), but if no intents have that tag it will return `None` - so be sure to handle this.

You can now access any parts of the intent `dict` by their keys e.g. `selected_intent['patterns']` - this would return the list of patterns for this tag. So you can do;

```
import random

patterns = selected_intent['patterns']
return_pattern = patterns[ random.randint(0, len(patterns)-1) ]

print(return_pattern) # output: whats up
```

This will generate a random `int` between 0 and the length of the list -1, which is used as an index to extract a random string from the list.

p.s. your `if` statements can be condensed with an `else` block because the second if is just the inverse of the first.

```
if message.strip() != "Bye":
    response = bot.get_response(message)
    print("ChatBot: ", response) 
else:
    print("ChatBot: Farewell")
    break
```

Comment: Your solution works, but how do I implement it into the chatbot?

Comment: And in the `i for i in in intents if i["tag"] == "greeting" ` how do I make the tag equal to all the tags instead of just greeting?

Comment: I'm not sure on the details of `chatterbot` - I was under the impression you already knew the `tag` and so needed to respond with a random `pattern`? If you get the `tag` from user input you can just load that into a variable e.g. `tag = input()` and then you can use `tag` in the generator `selected_intent = next((i for i in intents if i['tag'] == tag), None)`. How to implement the chat bot is beyond the scope of a single SO question - you might have to dig around in the docs :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I found a way to implement it into the chatbot. For loading `input()` into a variable and using it like that, it doesn't seem to be working, anytime I try the terminal gets stuck on execution. Is there a way to loop through the file and get all the tags?

Comment: You can get a list of the tags using [list comprehensions](https://medium.com/better-programming/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b) by `tags = [intent['tag'] for intent in intents]`