# Accessing a list in Python

Tags: python

So I have this list:

```
list1 = [['Car1', 'hyundai', 'blue', 'BF20E1'],['Car2', 'toyota', 'black', 'FD47GH']]
```

And I have this program:

```
choice = input('What car you want? ')
```

And now I want the program to search through the list and find it and print out the details of that certain car. E.g numberplate, colour, type.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I have been trying with for loops but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried?

Comment: Even the line `list1 ...` isn't valid Python. Have you been through a tutorial?

Comment: for x in list1:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Find in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Comment: Consider using a dictionary instead

Comment: for x in list1:
print([1])

Comment: i tried a dictionary too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in list1:
    if(x[0]==choice):
        print(x[1],x[2],x[3]
```

Hope that this would solve the problem