# Python query on list of dicts

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, dictionary

Hello I'm new with python (actually moving from VB)

In VB if I had d list of objects I could do something like this:

```
    Dim value_to_find = List_of_objects.Where(Function(x) x.Something).FirstOrDefault
```

on my current project, my data structure is a list of dicts. Something like this:

```
        [{Id:1,name:Bob, surname:Brown, dateB:07/12/1985,status:Active,code:202020, contact:1,
    list_of_dicts2[{id:1,dateB:07/07/2020},{id:2,dateB:07/08/2020}]}]
```

Now I want to access a certain dateB in the list_of_dicts2, if there a way to do it like in Visual Basic? or I have to loop through all of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Find in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Comment: You have to use a loop, one way or another. As an aside, you shouldn't use `dict` objects like this. Of course, often something like this is the result of some JSON, but `dict` objects aren't really record types, they are optimized to be *maps*

Comment: The `Linq` syntax you're used to using in VB.Net is essentially syntactic sugar for a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first date matching a condition using the `next` function and a comprehension.

```
next(d['dateB'] for d in list_of_dicts if your_condition)
```

`next` also allows a default value if none match your condition in the list:

```
next((d['dateB'] for d in list_of_dicts if your_condition), your_default_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
list(filter(lambda d: d['dateB']==value_to_find , list_of_dicts2))
```

Comment: Why use `list` and `filter`? Wouldn't a comprehension like `[d for d in list_of_dicts2 if d['dateB'] == value_to_find]` not only be more efficient but way easier to read?

Comment: Yes it can be done that way also, Will it be more efficient ? Haven't measured and More readable ? Depends on the reader

Comment: filter is mainly only faster when using small fast functions (usually builtin functions) not lambdas. Plus it has to do 2 lookups for the `list` and `filter` functions and create the lambda function. Comprehensions were made to be more readable and efficient and are the more preferred way over filter in the same manner that map is.

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter. It's not a bad answer and I'm not here to create conflict just discussing.

Comment: Yes, list comprehension works faster on bigger lists. Thanks