# How do I find an item in my list without using indexes

Tags: python, list

**How do I find an item in my list without using indexes.**

So i have a list and I want to find the item in a list.

Comment: Hi @MaxLime, let us understand your question by adding `more details` (the source code and the result you want to get)

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use the `.index()` function, or you don't want to use indexes generally?

Comment: Sorry I am just learning python so I don't really know but I know what to do now! Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Are you simply checking to see if an item exists within the list?**

If so user the **in** operator
Example:

```
# Example
my_list = [4,5,7,2,4,5]
if 7 in my_list:
   print("Item found")
```

**Or if you are trying to return the index of the item found do this:**

```
my_list.index(7)
# returns 2
```

Answer (score -1):

**If you have the list i would use this:**

fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'watermelon', 'peach']

index = fruits.index('apple')

print('The index of apple is:', index)

**OUTPUT:** 1