# Why is this "in" statement false?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write simple code in order to see if a string is in a list.
This is the code I've gotten.

```
a = ["Hill, Lauren", "Smith, Jerry"]
 
b = "Smith"
 
if b in a:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

I don't understand why it prints "False". I thought it would print "True" as "Smith" is in "Smith, Jerry".
Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: `Smith` and `"Smith, Jerry"` are not same. You can write it as `if any(b in x for x in a)`

Comment: `in` checks for exact match when you check something in list (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Comment: "I thought it would print "True" as "Smith" is in "Smith, Jerry"" - yeah, but you asked Python whether `"Smith"` was in the list, not whether it was in any of the list's elements, and `in` doesn't recurse implicitly like that.

Answer (score 0):

a = ["Hill, Lauren", "Smith, Jerry"]

b = "Smith"

if b in a:
print("True")
else:
print("False")

**Problem**
When you observe your last string properly you have created Smith,Jerry combined. When you are checking for b in list, It answers false because its not actually not in list

**Solution**
Correct your list and then run it will not give you an error

**Corrected Code**

```
a = ["Hill, Lauren", "Smith", "Jerry"]
```

b = "Smith"

if b in a:
print("True")
else:
print("False")

Answer (score 0):

You ask the interpreter to look if a String `("Smith")` is in a list`["Hill, Lauren", "Smith, Jerry"]`, which is not true.

However, if you ask if a String `("Smith")` is contained in `"Smith, Jerry"` this will be true.

If you want this to happen anyway:

```
a = ["Hill, Lauren", "Smith, Jerry"]
 
b = "Smith"

for ele in a:
    if b in ele:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Smith"` is in `"Smith, Jerry"`, but `"Smith, Jerry"` is in a list. `in` only works one layer, so to get the result you want you can try

```py
a = ["Hill, Lauren", "Smith, Jerry"]
 
b = "Smith"

if any(map(lambda x: b in x, a)):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

# or
if any([b in i for i in a]):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do it like that it is looking for an exact match.

```
if b in a:    #checks the list 'a' for value 'b'
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

If you want it to be true for partial matches, you would have to do something like this:

```
if any(b in x for x in a):    #checks each of the elements of list 'a' for value 'b'
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first list is have 2 value :
they are

1. "Hill, Lauren" and
2. "Smith, Jerry"

your code will work if the list is like this:

a = ["Hill", "Lauren", "Smith", "Jerry"]

if you want to get the true value, there are some ways:

1. first you can convert you list to correct list as I said above. then run your code
2. if you only check the name string, if exists or no , you can use regex expression
3. or if your list is fixed as above, you can use this:

> ```
>  if any(map(lambda x: b in x, a)):
>         print("True")
>     else:
>         print("False")
> ```