# Getting the first non None value from list

Tags: python, list

Given a list, is there a way to get the first non-None value? And, if so, what would be the pythonic way to do so?

For example, I have:

- `a = objA.addreses.country.code`
- `b = objB.country.code`
- `c = None`
- `d = 'CA'`

In this case, if a is None, then I would like to get b. If a and b are both None, the I would like to get d.

Currently I am doing something along the lines of `(((a or b) or c) or d)`, is there another way?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> a = [None, None, None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> next(item for item in a if item is not None)
1
```

If the list contains only Nones, it will throw `StopIteration` exception. If you want to have a default value in this case, do this:

```
>>> a = [None, None, None]
>>> next((item for item in a if item is not None), 'All are Nones')
All are Nones
```

Comment: I'd add a `try:` `except StopIteration:` to handle lists containing only None items. But that's a great answer.

Comment: @Germano updated the answer, please check. Btw, Jon's answer should be accepted - he was first to suggest a solution for None-only lists.

Comment: actually I think Jon's answer is not correct: it only returns `True` or `False`, not the first not `None` item of the list.

Comment: `None` evaluates to false in Python, so the `is not None` is redundant. This is like writing `if item is True`, and is not very Pythonic. Not sure why my edit got rejected for this...

Comment: @kevlar1818 `is not None` is more correct in this case since the OP wants to get the first *not-None* from the list.

Comment: @kevlar1818, if you leave out the "is not None", then it treats 0 and "" the same as it would treat a None (at least in my version of python)

Comment: @kevlar1818 try: `[x for x in [None, False, 0, '', True, None] if x is not None]` for more details

Comment: Nice to combine with Walrus operator when evaluating functions: 
`next((x for func in funcs if (x:= func(tree))), 'Default')`

Answer (score 37):

I think this is the **simplest way** when dealing with a small set of values:

```
firstVal = a or b or c or d
```

Will always return the first non "Falsey" value which works in some cases (given you dont expect any values which could evaluate to false as @GrannyAching points out below)

Comment: Not if there are any values that evaluate to False, such as: 0, '', [], (), False

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I overlooked that (updated post)

Comment: This is nice and terse. I wanted the first non-empty string.

Answer (score 19):

`first_true` is an `itertools` recipe found in the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def first_true(iterable, default=False, pred=None):
    """Returns the first true value in the iterable.

    If no true value is found, returns *default*

    If *pred* is not None, returns the first item
    for which pred(item) is true.

    """
    # first_true([a,b,c], x) --> a or b or c or x
    # first_true([a,b], x, f) --> a if f(a) else b if f(b) else x
    return next(filter(pred, iterable), default)
```

One may choose to implement the latter recipe or import `more_itertools`, a library that ships with `itertools` recipes and more:

```
> pip install more_itertools
```

Use:

```
import more_itertools as mit

a = [None, None, None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mit.first_true(a, pred=lambda x: x is not None)
# 1

a = [None, None, None]
mit.first_true(a, default="All are None", pred=lambda x: x is not None)
# 'All are None'
```

---

**Why use the predicate?**

"First non-`None`" item is not the same as "first `True`" item, e.g. `[None, None, 0]` where `0` is the first non-`None`, but it is not the first `True` item.  The predicate allows `first_true` to be useable, ensuring any first seen, non-None, falsey item in the iterable is still returned (e.g. `0`, `False`) instead of the default.

```
a = [None, None, None, False]
mit.first_true(a, default="All are None", pred=lambda x: x is not None)
# 'False'
```

Comment: Excellent!  A shame this is part of the standard lib.

Comment: Well the recipe is part of the docs.  You just have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 11):

When the items in your list are expensive to calculate such as in

```
first_non_null = next((calculate(x) for x in my_list if calculate(x)), None)

# or, when receiving possibly None-values from a dictionary for each list item:

first_non_null = next((my_dict[x] for x in my_list if my_dict.get(x)), None)
```

then you might want to avoid the repetitive calculation and simplify to:

```
first_non_null = next(filter(bool, map(calculate, my_list)), None)

# or:

first_non_null = next(filter(bool, map(my_dict.get, my_list)), None)
```

Thanks to the usage of a generator expression, the calculations are only executed for the first items until a truthy value is generated.

Comment: You can use map instead of a generator expression in python 3.

`first_non_null = next(filter(bool, map(my_dict.get, my_list)), None)`

Comment: That’s indeed more elegant, I’ve updated the answer with your suggestion

Comment: This will not output falsy values. For example, if `calculate = lambda it: it` and `my_list = [0, False, "", "foo"]`, your method will return `"foo"`. To filter out _only_ `None` values, replace `filter(bool, ...)` with `filter(lambda it: it is not None, ...)`.

Answer (score 7):

Adapt from the following (you could one-liner it if you wanted):

```
values = (a, b, c, d)
not_None = (el for el in values if el is not None)
value = next(not_None, None)
```

This takes the first non `None` value, or returns `None` instead.

Answer (score 4):

First of all want to mention that such function exists in SQL and is called [`coalesce`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp). Found no such thing in Python so made up my own one, using the recipe of @alecxe.

```py
def first_not_none(*values):
    return next((v for v in values if v is not None), None)
```

Really helps in cases like this:

```py
attr = 'title'
document[attr] = first_not_none(cli_args.get(attr), document_item.get(attr),
                                defaults_item.get(attr), '')
```