# How can I say check in one line "if a_list is empty or a_list[0].property == something" in one line?

Tags: python, list, comparison

Consider

```
teams = [[], []]
```

I want to add a people to teams, but only if (1) they for the same company as the others in the team OR (b) if the team is currently empty. The straight-forward way would be:

```
for team in teams:
    if len(team) > 0: # could also use "if bool(team):"
        if team[0].company == new_person.company:
           team.append(new_person)
           break
        else:
            continue
    else:
        team.append(new_person)
        break
else:
    teams.append([])
    teams[-1].append(new_person)
```

To me that seems like many lines to make a simple decision. The complicating factor is the possibility of an empty list, which will give me an error if I try to look at a property of one of its elements.

How can I say `if a_list is empty or a_list[0].property == something:` in one line?

Comment: `if (len(a_list) == 0) or (a_list[0].property == something):`?

Comment: a string does not have a function called: `property`

Comment: @U9-Forward: No, it's nor a duplicate. That post is only to check if a list is empty. I want to simultaneously check if a property in it has a certain value or not. I'll update the question a little to show this.

Answer (score 4):

You mean by this?:

```
...
if not a_list or a_list[0].property == something:
    ...
```

Comment: that line will give an error when the list is empty, because you are trying to call `a_list[0]`, but the list is empty.

Comment: Nop, when I try that I  get  `IndexError: list index out of range`. Did you actually use `a_list = []` to test that?

Comment: @levraininjaneer the second operand of the `or` operator is only evaluated if the first operand is false (since if the first is true then the expression is true, which is the definition of a logical or).

Comment: I stand corrected. I left the `not` out of my test. Thanks! I can work with this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# hasatrr -> some safety check
if not a_list or (hasatrr(a_list[0], 'property') and a_list[0].property == something)):
    <perform your operation>
else:
    <perform your else operation>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it by using what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363944/python-idiom-to-return-first-item-or-none), which I expanded on to get:

```
if next(iter(team, new_person)).company == new_person.company:
```

But U9-Forward's response is indeed the best way to do it, I think.
Also, great to keep in mind what bruno desthuilliers said:

" the second operand of the `or` operator is only evaluated if the first operand is false (since if the first is true then the expression is true, which is the definition of a logical or"