# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'first'

Tags: python, django

```
lebel_months = []
members_exps = []  

for member in team.members.all():
    qs = Profile.objects.expenses_per_month(member.user)
    clr = color_picker()
    member_qs = []
    for exp in qs:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=exp.user_id)
        month = exp.month
        summary = exp.sum
        if month not in lebel_months and month is not None:
            lebel_months.append(month)
        if month is not None and summary is not None:                
            member_qs.append({
                'user': user.username, 
                'clr': clr, 
                'month': month, 
                'summary': summary})
    if member_qs:
        members_exps.append(member_qs)

print(members_exps[0])
print(members_exps.first())
```

outputs:
with [0] everything works

```
[{'user': 'serj', 'clr': '#71CABC', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 
'summary': 128400}, {'user': 'serj', 'clr': '#71CABC', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1, 0, 0, 
tzinfo=<UTC>), 'summary': 53500}]
```

with first()

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'first'
```

First print statement works. Second print statement catch an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? The error message clearly describes what happens: `members_exps` is a list, which doesn't have a `first` method.

Comment: I wanted get information like `members_exps.first.user` and it's not work

Comment: It doesn't work because `members_exp` doesn't have a `first` method.

Comment: Ok. thanks. I understood. How can I get 'user' useing `members|first|first` in template?

Comment: What kind of object has a `first` method?

Comment: @hpaulj, this is also my question, did you ever get am answer?

Comment: @ClementOseiTano, one of the answers says `pandas` dataframes have a `first` method, which is easily verified.  That said, I don't see evidence that the OP is using pandas.

Comment: @hpaulj I later found out the the object I needed was a Queryset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, members_exps = [] declares List type.

Lists/Arrays don't have a first() method. There's a list of available methods: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp

If you want to get the first item of the List you might be interested to read the following thread: [Python idiom to return first item or None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363944/python-idiom-to-return-first-item-or-none)

Comment: > Lists/Arrays don't have a first() method.  
Indeed, because why would you ever want such a method?  Perhaps in Python 4; after all, Python finally got a switch statement in 3.10 after 30 years.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the members_exps variable is a list, and in python lists do not have a first() attribute/function. first only works for dataframes.